# Ajax request fails with 419 status in Laravel with Varnish on top

Tags: ajax, laravel, varnish

We have a server setup and everything works fine, now we have implemented Varnish on top of our webserver to handle cache.
Ajax post request ends up with 419 status code. I searched through many forums and googled in which most of them have mentioned it must be a csrf token issue.

Steps i have followed and confirmed:

1. Made sure csrf is included in header meta tag - Yes
2. Script tag to add headers to all Ajax requests - Yes
3. Tried adding the csrf token header explicitly into the POST request - Yes

But still it ends up in 419 status code.

Anyone faced the same issue, can anyone help me on this?

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  url: BASE_URL + '/userlogin',
  data: {
    //'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
    'email': $("#log_email").val(),
    'password': $("#log_password").val(),
    'remember': remember,
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'post',
  success: function (response) {
    if(response.type =='success') {
     //some code here
    }
    else {
     //some code here
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

-Vijay